# JSON from php file to java array

Tags: android, json, android-activity

I know that there are a few question about this subject, but I read them and I tried the soluttion but it didn't work :(

the PHP script give this json array result: data[x] =

```
         ["alon","62","1.82","22","0","70","0","1"]
```

(this is the data[x] variable)

I have to convert this result to Java variabls like name,weight,height etc.. but I don't know how..

please help me

my function:

```
        private class LongOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {





        private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        private String Error = null;

        protected void onPreExecute() {


        }

        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                  HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                data[x] = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Error = e.getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error2" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                cancel(true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Error = e.getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error34" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                cancel(true);
            }

            return null;
        }

        public void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

            String name = null,weight = null;
            if (Error != null) {  
            } else {

                // here I have to do something with the arrays... 

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"d:" + data[x] + "o:" + name + " : " + weight, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
             }
            x++;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Modal Class for that.

```
class myModal {
   private String name, weight, height, ...;
   public String getName() { return this.name; } 
   public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
   //and more getters and setters
}


JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data[x]); // in your sample its a JSONArray but its wrong formatted. make sure you encode it properply with php json_encode(array("data", yourdata))...);

myModal modal = new myModal();
modal.setName(json.getString("name"));
```

php should be something like

```
<?php 
  $data = array("name" => "myname", "weight" => 20);
  print json_encode(  $data  ); 
?>
```

while the json can be parsed in this case with

```
 JSONArray json = new JSONArray(data);
 for (int i = 0; i <= json.length();i++){
   JSONObject jsonObj = json.getJsonObject(i);
   myModal modal = new myModal();
   modal.setString(jsonObj.getString("name"));
  //and so on          
 }
```

make sure to read the basics for understanding

Comment: I tried what you said. still doesn't work =[ php shows this: ["data",{"name":"alon","weight":"62","height":"1.82","age":"22","weeks":"0","target":"70","ketzev":"0","gender":"1"}]   .  eclipse wants to add try and catch to your code: JSONObject json = null;
try {
 json = new JSONObject(data[x]);
} catch (JSONException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
}
myModal modal = new myModal();
try {
 modal.setName(json.getString("name"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: php file:   $data = array("name" => "$name","weight" => "$weight","height" => "$height","age" => "$age","weeks" => "$weeks","target" => "$target","ketzev" => "$ketzev","gender" => "$gender");
  $length=count($array);

   echo json_encode(array("data", $data));